# Can't login with the set password deployed by proxmox in CoreOS

Tags: login, proxmox, coreos

I have tried to install CoreOS to my VM in proxmox, I have create a file cloud-config.yaml:

```
#cloud-config

hostname: coreos

coreos:  
  etcd:    
    addr: $private_ipv4:4001
    peer-addr: $private_ipv4:7001
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
    - name: static.network
      runtime: true
      content: |
        [Match]
        Name=ens18

        [Network]
        Address=192.168.4.109/24
        Gateway=192.168.4.1
        DNS=8.8.8.8
users:  
  - name: core
    passwd: core
    groups:
      - sudo
      - docker
```

I have load live ISO at boot and launch this command:

```
sudo coreos-install -d /dev/sda -c cloud-config.yaml
```

CoreOS install correctly but I can't login with user and password "core", where is the error?

Comment: Can you use another password other than core?  I would suspect that the user/pass can't be the same, security risk.  Change it to another password.

Comment: Not work, after installation, seems to ignore completely the configuration file , do not configure the network even

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify a hash for the [passwd](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/blob/master/Documentation/cloud-config.md#users) option in the `#cloud-config` file.

```
$ echo "core" | openssl passwd -stdin -1
$1$o2SU8wJ7$IUhyYV.5yJ5TI7BSZmZDx.
```